# Hack a website using database username and password

Tags: databases, mysql

Is it possible that someone could hack a website if they have the database name, database username, and database password? If so, how do they do it?
The database connection is mysql.

Comment: So basically what you are asking is "how to connect to mysql with a username, password, and database name"? Because "hacking a website" when you already have the password... that's like asking how to open a car when you already have the key?

Comment: I think some clarification is needed... if you have connection details/credentials, you _may_ be able to access the database, depending on whether the server is exposed to the outside world. For a heavily database-dependent website (using some kind of content-management system), that might allow you to "hack the website" to some degree or other, but not necessarily let you do "all" things to it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if your database is exposing itself to the internet. A database can be configured to listen on the network in order for other, authorized computers to connect. If it is exposed *and* all this information is public, then anyone will be able to perform privileged actions on that database even if they shouldn't.

Still, you shouldn't be revealing your database credentials, or other local processes on your server might be able to connect to the database locally (not through the network) if they have been compromised.

Comment: Also vulnerable if you have `phpmyadmin` or similar installed

Comment: @forest But isn't that hacking the database and not the *website*?

Comment: @schroeder I'd think people would consider a website with a hacked database to be a hacked website.

Comment: @forest I get that, of course, but I'm wondering about connecting some dots for the OP. My suspicion is that the OP does not have access to the database, but has access to the website.

Comment: @schroeder Then I think OP should elaborate on exactly what they mean. They do say that the database is mysql, so I don't think they're just throwing that term around without meaning, well, a _database_.

Comment: hacking the database may allow privilege escalation for the website user

Comment: @forest I was interpreting the situation from the perspective of "the connection is mysql", which would mean the connection from the website to the database. And that is not typically exposed.